# md-checkbox to behave like radio button - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying `md-checkbox` to behave like radio button in Angular 1. I tried with the following code and is not working. Is it possible?

```
<md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="color" name="color" ng-repeat="c in colors" ng-true-value="'{{c.id}}'" ng-false-value="">
    {{c.name}}
</md-checkbox>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the material radio button instead?

Comment: @Soviut  I want that tick mark in `md-checkbox` to be applied in my UI and it should behave like a radio button. `md-radio-button` has dot style only right? Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a ng-model in each checkbox. Is pretty simple if your take advantage of `ng-checked` and `ng-click`... [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/t9VwzZ6WIFJDVWEoR8K8?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<md-checkbox ng-repeat="c in colors"
           ng-click="setSelectedColor(c)"
           ng-checked="c.id === selectedColor.id">
    {{c.name}}
</md-checkbox>
```

**CONTROLER:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [{id: 1, name: 'red'}, {id: 2, name: 'green'}];
    $scope.selectedColor; //You can set a initial selection if you want

    $scope.setSelectedColor = function(c){
        $scope.selectedColor = c;
    };
});
```

Comment: This is working fine. Is it possible to do validation without `ng-model`? Can you tell me how can I do validation with your answer?

Comment: What do you want to validate? That one option has to be selected?

Comment: I am asking like adding `ng-required` in it so that it will get reflected in `formName.colorName.$invalid` right? Is there a way to do like this?

Comment: You are right, if you want to to use validation, you have to use `ng-model`. I had made a workaround to make it work, but you only can check that user select at least one option. Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KuCAULVDdkNWHNWfhiR2?p=preview).

Comment: But as other users say, if you have a radio button control, this is a lot of work to get the same functionality. Anyway, let me know if you still have some problems with the plunker...

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Really appreciate it. The plunker is working perfect. And as other users say with accessibility concerns, I will try to use customized radio button to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a checkbox when you need a radio button. If you want the radio button to have a check mark, apply the same classes that the md-checkbox uses to the radio buttons.

It's a really bad idea to use the wrong form controls for the sake of aesthetics; There's all sorts of accessibility concerns such as how they'll be treated on mobile, by screen readers for the blind, etc. Think about it this way, if you wanted a red button, you'd style the button to be red. In this case, just style the radio to look like a check.

Answer (score 0):

should work if you will pass like `ng-true-value="{{c.id}}"`

According to the angular material [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox):

> ng-true-value - **expression** - The value to which the expression should be set when selected.

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh git it what you want, will agree with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000935/5727598

Answer (score 0):

It should be as follows,

```
 <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="color" name="color" ng-repeat="c in colors" ng-true-value="'c.id'" ng-false-value="">
        {{c.name}}
 </md-checkbox>
```

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [{
    id: '001',
    name: "pink"
  }, {
    id: '002',
    name: "yellow"
  }];


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>Test angular md-select with material 0.11.0</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="color" name="color" ng-repeat="c in colors" ng-true-value="'c.id'" ng-false-value="">
    {{c.name}}
  </md-checkbox>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried with your code, but it is not behaving like radio button. Moreover, it is not getting me the `ng-model` value.